# Button search and function

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I have filter/search here. But the search is when I'm insert the value and get ENTER it success. Right now, I want to change the search with button search and textarea for input the value. It is supposed to have like that. Do I need to add search button? Please see my demo below, thank you.

[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/ivOLOXig)

> I have done this

[image: Pic1]

> I want to change to this

[image: pic2]

> HTML

```
    <input id="text" type="text" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Search by name" />
```

> JavaScript

```
$('#text').change(function(e){
        var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
        var field = 'ProductName';
        var operator = 'contains';
        var value = this.value;
        grid.dataSource.filter({
          field: field,
          operator: operator,
          value: value
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: what is the actual problem you have here? What have you done to arrive at your current point and what have you done to solve it?

Comment: I have edit above, please take a look@SimasJoneliunas

Comment: Please include [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of providing a link to the whole website

Comment: Could you please clarify what your question is & what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want button search there and be function with textbox

Comment: You have the function running when the textbox input change event fires. If you want it to run when a user clicks a button, you'd need to change it to be that instead. If that doesn't answer your question, you need to be more clear on what you need help with.

Comment: Yes, that's I want. Thank you, i will edit again for the expalanation. @Nikki9696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a button

```
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" />
```

Change this

```
$('#text').change(function(e){
```

to this

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function(e){
```